# MySQL - Sort results in descending order of overall count

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table as below

**year -------- org ------- name ---------- category -------- points**
2005 -------- ABC ------- N1   ---------- CAT1     -------- 10
2006 -------- DEF ------- N2   ---------- CAT2     -------- 5
etc

Primary key in this table is (year, org, name)

I need an output as below

**org ------- category ------ points *(sorted in descending order of overall points of org)***
DEF ------- CAT1     ------ 1000
DEF ------- CAT2     ------ 5000
DEF ------- CAT3     ------ 2000
ABC ------- CAT1     ------ 6000
ABC ------- CAT2     ------ 100
ABC ------- CAT3     ------ 50

**DEF** score is 8000 which is higher than the score of **ABC** which is 6150. So appears at the top of the expected output

I wrote a select statement as below

**select org, cat, count(cat) from table where year=2006 group by org, cat order by org**

I get the result ordered by **org** but I am unable to get the output sorted in descending order of overall count of points of every type of **org**

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks - Praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN to group the `org` alone, and get the `SUM` of all the counts for each group:

```
SELECT t.org, t.cat, count(t.cat)
FROM table t JOIN (
    SELECT org, count(cat) SumCount
    FROM table
    WHERE year=2006 
    GROUP BY org
) tg ON t.org = tg.org
WHERE t.year = 2006 
GROUP BY t.org, t.cat
ORDER BY MAX(rs.SumCount), t.org DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the query u use desc keyword, which will help u out